# Can I time a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Is there a way to put some sort of a timer on my for(;;) loop? I want my loop to run about every 1 or 2 seconds. How do I do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(;;){
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: Let the loop do its stuff, then sleep the remaining time till the next interval. [`Thread.sleep`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_sleep_millis.htm).

Comment: Or express it as a Runnable and give it to a scheduled executor.